# Weird behaviour block placement, Raycast, hit.normal. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a simple block placing script.
Everything seems to be working when static (When it has no Rigidbody)
but when i add the rigidbody and i try to place a block on it, it won't appear. when i look in the hierarchy it goes to a very strange position under the ground (Terrian) or inside a already placed block.

Here's the script:

```
var TheBlock = Instantiate(Blocks[0], hit.transform.position +hit.normal / 4, Quaternion.identity);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this strange behaviour/ explain why it does this?

Thanks in advance!

-Shinevision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when i add the rigidbody and i try to place a block on it, it
>   won't appear. when i look in the hierarchy it goes to a very strange
>   position under the ground (Terrian) or inside a already placed block.

It is very likely that when `Rigidbody` is attached, gravity is pulling the Object. The default gravity would pull it down even under the terrain. Disable `useGravity` after instantiating the object.

```
var TheBlock = Instantiate(Blocks[0], hit.transform.position + hit.normal / 4, Quaternion.identity);
TheBlock.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
```